# What is the usage of 'half-way' and 'underway'?

Tags: phrase-usage

How have you done with your project?

1) I have done half-way.

2) I am half-way.

3) It is underway.

Are these three answers all correct?

Comment: In AmE the question would more likely be:  "How's the project going?" which doesn't necessarily require you to say how far you've gotten—you might reply "so far so good".  If he says "How's the project coming along?", you probably should reply with a guess at how far you have progressed, and let him know if you have hit any "snags" (problems that delay your progress).  If he says "how far [along] are you on that projecf?"  He's definitely expecting your best estimation of when you will complete it.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) I have done half-way.
>   2) I am half-way.

I think you'll find those first two you've listed are more commonly expressed as:

- *I'm halfway done*.

or maybe:

- *I have the first half done.*
- *I'm done with the first half.*

> 3) It is underway.

The third one is fine, but it usually means you've only just started, and are nowhere near the halfway point yet. You could also say, "I'm underway," just as easily as, "It's underway." (Conversationally, I think you'll find contractions to be appropriate here.)

Comment: In an informal way even *half done* works. Maybe, because you cannot do the second half first in a project!